# How can I get access to props of a component inside the getServerSideProps() function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to send some parameters in a React component and then want to access value of those parameters inside the getServerSideProps function of the component. Is there anyway to do this?

I am using next framework of React js.

```
  <Menu name={menuName} />
```

Here I am sending the name parameter in the Menu component. Now I want to access value of 'name' in the getServerSideProps function of Menu component. Can anybody who can do so?

Comment: `getServerSideProps` is what defines the props for a page, and gets executed before your components get rendered. It can't be used in your `Menu` component, it's only available in pages. For more details see: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

If Your Menu component is a child, then define useState hook in parent like so:

```
const [name, setName] = React.useState('default name');
```

Than pass it like:

```
<Menu name={name} setName={setName} />
```

In Menu component than extract it trough props like:

```
function Menu (props) {

// props.name and props.setName availible

}

// or

function Menu ({name, setName}) {}
```